# Se Chartjs horizontal

Tags: angularjs, chart.js, ionic4

I want to create a horizontal bar chart like this photo using [Chartjs](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/bar/horizontal.html) library

[image]

So I follow the instructions and I have something like:

**TS:**

```
 createAreaChart() {
this.barChart1 = document.getElementById('barChart1');
this.ctx1 = this.barChart1.getContext('2d');

 let i = 0;
this.data1.forEach(div => {
  if(i==0){
    this.backgroundColors.push('#A60A2D');
  } if(i==1) {
    this.backgroundColors.push('#00A2C3');
  } if(i==2) {
    this.backgroundColors.push('#434F55');
    i = -1;
  }
  i++;
});

this.chart1 = new Chart(this.ctx1, {
      type: 'bar',
      data: {
        labels: this.data1.map(r => r.icon),
        datasets: [{
          data: this.data1.map(r => r.total),
          label: 'Annual Cost',
          backgroundColor: this.backgroundColors,
          borderColor: this.backgroundColors,
          borderWidth: 1
        }]
      },
      options: {
        legend: {
          display: false
        },
        tooltips: {
          callbacks: {
            label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
              var value = data.datasets[0].data[tooltipItem.index];
              if (parseInt(value) >= 1000) {
                return '$' + value.toFixed(2).toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
              } else {
                return '$' + value.toFixed(2).toString();
              }
            }
          }
        },
        scales: {
          yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
              beginAtZero: true,
              precision: 2,
              userCallback : function(value, index, values) {
                if(parseInt(value) >= 1000){
                  return '$' + value.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
                } else {
                  return '$' + value;
                }
              }
            }
          }]
        }
      }
    });
    this.chart1.height = 225;

    }
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="card chart-card">
      <div class="card-header">
        <div class="card-title">Test</div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <div class="chart">
          <canvas id="barChart1" height="220px"></canvas>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

But for some reason I get a vertical bar like this:

[image]

How can I do to change it to be horizontally orientation, the current Y axis be at X axis and above each bar use current X axis, exactly like the first photo? Regards

**UPDATE**

As the comment below I currently using [Chartjs V 2.9.4](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/2.9.4/charts/bar.html#horizontal-bar-chart), now it works, the chart is oriented horizontally

[image]

Now, I need to place Y axis text above each bar, is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you're still using `Chart.js version 2`. The current latest version is `3.5.1`.

Change `type: 'bar'` into `type: 'horizontalBar'` and it should work.

```
new Chart(this.ctx1, {
  type: 'horizontalBar',
  ...
```

> For further details, please consult [Horizontal Bar Chart](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/2.9.4/charts/bar.html#horizontal-bar-chart) from the `Chart.js v2.9.4` documentation.

Comment: Yes, it works! I updated my question, is it possible to set text above each bar?

Comment: @Jesus: Please mark this answer as accepted if you think it was the solution to your original problem. Then post a new question for this new issue, don't chain questions within the same post.

Answer (score 0):

Add this:

```
options: {
    indexAxis: 'y',
    ...
}
```

[Here](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/bar/horizontal.html#horizontal-bar-chart) is ChartJS documentation

Comment: I tried, but it still shows vertical